# How to iterate through a splice in go/golang for a HTML page?

Tags: html, go

I've looked through online examples and other splice examples, but haven't succeeded.

Here's my HTML

```
<table style="width:100%">
  <tr>
    <th>Source</th>
    <th>Title</th>
    <th>Author</th>
    <th>URL</th>
  </tr>
  {{range .Arts}}
    <tr>
      <td>{{ .Source }}</td>
      <td>{{ .Title }}</td>
      <td>{{ .Author }}</td>
      <td>{{ .URL }}</td>
    </tr>
  {{end}}  
</table>
```

GO:

```
Source string
    Author string
    Title  string
    URL    string
}

type NewsPage struct {
    Header   string
    News     string
    Articles []Article
}

var Arts []Article

func newsDisplayHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    //  temp := template.Must(template.ParseFiles("layout.html"))
    newsPage := NewsPage{
        Header:   "This is your Mostly Fake news update for " + time.Now().Format("Mon 2006-01-2"),
        News:     "Here's your daily dose of mostly Fake News",
        Articles: Arts}
    parse, _ := template.ParseFiles("newsPage.html")
    parse.Execute(w, newsPage)
    //  temp.Execute(w, newsPage)
}
```

What am I missing? The rest of my code works and is not the issue here. My issues is that I am not able to loop through my slice to add it to the HTML table. I wont know the number of Articles at run time, as I'm getting the info from an API.

Comment: You should be examining the returned errors rather than discarding them. You would see that `.Arts` is an invalid field, but should rather be `.Articles`.

Comment: silly me. Thanks

Answer (score -1):

From the code you provided, the array is empty and as the documentation reads:

> If the value of the pipeline has length zero, nothing is output;

Your HTML looks fine.

You're also never passing the array:

try:

```
newsPage := NewsPage{
    Arts: Arts
}
```

instead of

```
newsPage := NewsPage{
    Articles: Arts
}
```